# If $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot e^{\frac{1}{x}}$, and $x_{0}\in \left ( 0,\frac{1}{2} \right )$, let $x_{n+1}=f\left ( \frac{1}{x_{n}} \right )$. Show:

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus \left \{ 0 \right \}\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot e^{\frac{1}{x}}$
$x_{0}\in \left ( 0,\frac{1}{2} \right )$, $x_{n+1}=f\left ( \frac{1}{x_{n}} \right ) \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

Show that:
1) $(x_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent
2) $\lim_{n\to\ \infty }x_{n} = 0$

EDIT: Well, going to that link, someone says that $x_{0}$ is important when talking about the convergente of the sequence, and that's what that specific person forgot to mention.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt Can you solve it now that you have $x_{0}$ interval ?

Comment: Since $\frac12e^{\frac12}=\frac{\sqrt{e}}2<1$ you get $\frac12<\hat{x}$ with the notation from my answer in the link and therefore $x_0\in(0,1/2)\subset (0,\hat{x})$ and case 1 holds.